# C++, Что я сделал не так?

Tags: c++, циклы

Нужно написать программу, которая с помощью циклов посчитала произведение всех двузначных чисел, кратных 5 и 2. Написал вот эту программу, а оно не правильно считает, подскажите пожалуйста что не так?

```
int main()
{
    int mul = 1;
    int rangeBegin = 10; 
    int rangeEnd = 99;
    do
    {
        if (rangeBegin % 2 == 0 && rangeBegin % 5 == 0)
        {
            mul *= rangeBegin;
        }
        rangeBegin++;
    } while (rangeBegin<rangeEnd);
    cout << "multiplication= " << mul << endl;
}
```

Comment: Из комментариев к предыдущему вашему вопросу: `Заведите переменную для результата (только достаточно большого типа, например, unsigned long long). Инициализируйте её единицей.`

Comment: Проблема в переменной маленького типа?

Comment: Да. Точный ответ — `9! * 10^9`. Данное значение слишком велико, чтобы поместиться в 32-битный тип `int`.

Comment: Спасибо! Только теперь оно записывает как 3.6288е+14. Можно как то сделать что бы писало полное число?

Comment: Можно. Посчитайте факториал девяти и допишите к нему девять нулей.

Comment: Вероятно вы использовали для переменной `mul` тип с плавающей точкой `float`, либо `double`, либо `long double`. Или же вы тестируете какой-то другой код, а не приведённый в вопросе,, в котором используется функция `pow()`. Просто напишите `long long mul = 1;`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я просто до этого написал long double mul = 1.